# Save Webpage (including images) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to save webpage(including images).

Actually i saved the webpage using the following code.

```
Dim LocalFilePath As String = String.Format("D:\Jaison\Download\{0}.html",
                               Me.TextBox1.Text)
Dim objWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
objWebClient.DownloadFile(
                 String.Format("http://localhost:52241/ppp.aspx?hr_psno={0}", 
                        Me.TextBox1.Text), LocalFilePath)
```

It saves the webpage.

But the image is not shown in the saved webpage.

So plz help me for further coding.

Comment: Tried to reload your pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is nothing but save and show the images using correct path.
For Ex:
     Instead of using the url from local folder*(D:\Jaison\Download{0}.html)* we can give use the url like *(../Images/{0}.html)* and save that in **Project folder** not in **Local folder**. 
     That saves and shows the images with perfect manner.

Thank you guys...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a lot more than just getting the html file and downloading that, think of the following:

1. You need to download the HTML file
2. You need to scan the HTML file for image/css/script references & download those too
3. You then need to change the references in the original HTML file to reference the new location and not the potentially absolute references on the website

While the following app is not VB.NET it may give you a better understanding of the requirements: [WinHttrack](http://www.httrack.com/), the code is available on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program called: **Dragon Scraper**. It will allow you to save the images in a variety of extensions or all extensions using checkboxes. A folder will automatically be created to your desktop called: **Collections**. A text file of the html code will also be saved in the same folder and the program will also display the html code in a textbox for you. It takes but a moment to process, roughly 5 seconds tops.
**Items needed:**

5 **Checkboxes** (data binding names: Png, Tif, Gif, Jpg, Png, Bmp)

2 **Buttons** (one named **Seeker**, the other named **Clear**)

1 **Textbox** (named default >> **Textbox1.Text**)

1 **Vertical Scrollbar** for **Textbox1**

1 **Timer1** (Interval 5000) **Enable False**

```
'Created by: Justin Linwood Ross (May 2022)
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly htmlsource As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Collection\source.txt"

    Private ReadOnly portfolio As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Collection\images"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'This will create a desktop folder if one doesn't exist
        If Not Directory.Exists($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\Collection") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\Collection")
        End If

        'Creates TextBox text
        Dim filepath As String = htmlsource
        If Not File.Exists(filepath) Then
            File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
        End If


        PictureBox1.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "../../Images/face.jpg")
        PictureBox2.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "../../Images/face.jpg")
    End Sub

    Function GetImagesFromURL(URL As String)
        Dim i As Integer = -1
        Dim Picturez(3000) As Image
        Dim cl As HttpWebRequest
        cl = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        Dim receive As HttpWebResponse = cl.GetResponse
        Dim WStream As Stream = receive.GetResponseStream

        ' Create reader object
        Dim Basin As New StreamReader(WStream)
        Dim items As String = Basin.ReadToEnd
        'Why use this expression??? >>> "src\=\""[\u0000-\uFFFF]*?\.(gif|png|jpg|tif|bmp)\""" 
        'It searches for a string like src="AnyCharForMinimumLength.gif or png or jpg or tif or bmp"
        For Each Rythorian As Match In Regex.Matches(items, "src\=\""[\u0000-\uFFFF]*?\.(gif|png|jpg|tif|bmp)\""") 'for each match"

            Dim Kreznok As String = Rythorian.Value
            Kreznok = Kreznok.TrimStart("s", "r", "c", "=", """").TrimEnd("""") ' it clears the url from src=" and "

            Try
                Try
                    'if is a full url then create a new web request
                    cl = WebRequest.Create(Kreznok) 'if this fails then this is not a complete url
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' if is not the full url then combine the given URL with the image path and get rid of any \\ if they exists ( www.mysite.com//image.gif to www.mysite.com/image.gif)
                    cl = WebRequest.Create((URL & "/" & Kreznok).Replace("//", "/"))

                End Try

                receive = cl.GetResponse
                WStream = receive.GetResponseStream

                i += 1
                'write the image into an array(list) of images
                Picturez(i) = Image.FromStream(WStream)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next

        Return Picturez

    End Function

    Private Sub Seeker_Click(sender As Object,
                             e As EventArgs) Handles Seeker.Click

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each img As Image In GetImagesFromURL(UrlHost.Text.ToString) '"https://moviestowatch.tv/movie"
            Try
                If img IsNot Nothing Then

                    If Png.Checked Then
                        img.Save($"{portfolio}{i}.png")
                        i += 1
                    ElseIf Gif.Checked Then
                        img.Save($"{portfolio}{i}.gif")
                        i += 1
                    ElseIf Jpg.Checked Then
                        img.Save($"{portfolio}{i}.jpg")
                        i += 1
                    ElseIf Bmp.Checked Then
                        img.Save($"{portfolio}{i}.bmp")
                        i += 1
                    ElseIf Tif.Checked Then
                        img.Save($"{portfolio}{i}.tif")
                        i += 1
                    End If

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'when it's done it gives an error telling us that there is no image in the next img, so we stop
                Exit For
            End Try

        Next

        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object,
                                  e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        Dispose()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End Sub



    Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object,
                            e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click

        Png.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Tif.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Gif.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Bmp.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Jpg.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(UrlHost.Text.ToString())

        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            File.WriteAllText(htmlsource, html)

        End Using

        Try
            Dim array = File.ReadAllLines(htmlsource)

            For i1 = 0 To array.Length - 1

                Dim sz As String = array(i1)
                TextBox1.AppendText(sz + vbNewLine)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The program can be found at my repository. I hope you all enjoy it.

**Link:**

https://github.com/Rythorian77/Dragon-Scraper/releases/tag/v1.0

**Video Demonstration:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBtDqNvskwE